# Get the records matching the combination of column values from a temporary table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2016

I have a temp table with 4 columns

question_tbl:

## TempTable -- combination to lookup

```
id      | Code1    | Code2       | code3
--------+----------+-------------+---------
111       | AA       | A1          | X
222       | BB       | B1          | Y
333       | CC       | C1          | Z
444       | DD       | D1          | ZZ
```

Code1 and Code2 are columns in tableA , Code3 is in tableB

Table A has Records

```
DeptID      | Code1    | Code2       | 
--------+----------+-------------+---------
A           | AA       | A1          | 
B           | BC       | B1          | 
C           | CC       | C1          | 
D           | DC       | D1          | 
E           | DD       | D1          |
```

Table B has Records

```
DeptID      | Code1     
--------+----------+-------------+---------
A           | X
B           | XX       
C           | Z       
D           | YY       
E           | Z Z
```

I have to use the temptable to lookup on both table A and B.
If I find the 3 combinations matching using both tables, then I append Id 
value from Temp to DeptId in TableB
So my final result should be

```
DeptID      | Code1     
--------+----------+-------------+---------
A111           | X
C333           | Z       
E444           | ZZ
```

The query that I am using currently is as below. It is working fine. But gives 
   me a performance issue because number of records in table A and B are more 
   than  20000

```
SELECT B.DeptID + T.ID
FROM TableA                                 A
INNER JOIN #TMP                             T 
    ON T.Code3  = A.Code3
INNER JOIN TableB                           B
    ON B.Code1  = T.Code1  AND B.Code2 =  T.Code2
```

is there any other alternative way to lookup the combinations on the table? 
Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select cast([Dept].[DeptID] as varchar(100)) + cast([TT].[id] as varchar(100)) [DeptID],
       [Dept].[Code3]
from (
    select [A].[DeptID] [DeptID],
           [A].[Code1] [Code1],
           [A].[Code2] [Code2],
           [B].[Code1] [Code3]
    from TableA [A]
    join TableB [B] on [A].DeptID = [B].DeptID
) [Dept] left join TempTable [TT] on
([Dept].[Code1] = [TT].[Code1] and [Dept].[Code2] = [TT].[Code2] and [Dept].[Code3] = [TT].[Code3])
where [TT].[id] is not null
```